# Null Session Share not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I have a computer running Windows 7 SP 1 Ultimate (IP 192.168.11.100). I need to create a **Null Session Share** (named *WIA_RIS_SHARE*) for [Serva PXE Server](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/advanced/NullSessionShares.html) to be able to install Windows XP via networking.

According to [its docs](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/advanced/NullSessionShares.html), I have created:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\NullSessionShares = "WIA_RIS_SHARE"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\restrictanonymous = 0
```

I have done it at a **Windows XP SP3** (IP 192.168.11.2), and it seems to work OK.

This is how I check it (from another computer on the same LAN):

```
C:\>net view \\192.168.11.2
Shared resources at \\192.168.11.2
Resource name           Type    Used ad Comments
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WIA_RIS_SHARE       Disk
```

But when checking it on the Win7 machine:

```
C:\>net view \\192.168.11.100
System error 5.
Access denied.
```

As far as I know, it is supposed that a Null Share Session should allow browsing (enumeration) of shared resources, so I believe this is a appropriate test.

What else could I need to do to **enable Null Session Shares** on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you didn't read [Serva's NSS documentation](http://vercot.com/~serva/advanced/NullSessionShares.html) correctly; please click on the "**WINDOWS 7**" chapter.

**For Windows 7 hosted NSSs when clients are RIS** these are the shown steps:

```
1. Enabling Anonymous Logon:

   1. Run the Control Panel

   2. Navigate to:

   Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Change advanced sharing settings\

   Select:

   Turn off password protected sharing

   3. Save changes and close the Control Panel.

2. Creating the Share:

    1. From File Explorer right click the TFTP root directory and select "Properties."

    2. Select the "Sharing" tab and click [Advanced Sharing...]

    3. Check "Share this folder", set "Share Name" = WIA_RIS_SHARE and click [Permissions]

    4. Remove all users/groups then add the user "Guest" with "Read" rights only and 
       click [OK] twice.

    5. Back at the Properties dialog now select the "Security" tab and click [Edit...]

    6. Click [Add..], enter the user "Guest" and click [OK]

    7. Selecting the user "Guest" at the "Group or user names:" pane edit its permissions 
       at the "Permissions for Guest" pane. Make sure you check the "Allow" column with 
       "Read & execute", "List folder contents" and, "Read" permissions, then click 
       [OK] twice.
```

Just in the case you need to create an NSS for clients (**other than RIS**) that mandatorily require older dialects like “LANMAN1.0”, “LANMAN1.2”, etc, then you might need extra steps in order to enable those dialects at your host; i.e.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\NullSessionShares = "WIA_RIS_SHARE"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\restrictanonymous = 0
```

In your case these extra steps are not necessary as you are booting RIS clients...

Comment: Thanks you, @Patt. Indeed, you were right: I didn't read the docs correctly. The problem was a bit ridiculous: the `Windows X` list at that URL didn't seem to me as a **drop-down menu**, so I thought it was merely an informative pane :-D. Maybe the classic drop-down button on the right would have helped. Anyway, a **curious thing**: I have a Windows XP SP3 running following those docs, but without any need to `turn off password protected sharing`. The rest of the config I made is exactly as you said.

Comment: The original question was not *How to configure Serva*, but rather * how to enable Null Session Share*. Anyway, the method is just the same, so I have marked your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: 1) "turn off password protected sharing" is not needed when the host is Windows XP; read Serva's NSS instructions. 2) I think my answer does not say how to configure Serva; It just quote the steps (from Serva's website) for correctly creating an NSS on a Windows 7 host as you requested. I'm glad you got it working.